# Constructing 3D Geometry of a room from an Array of Cameras

Tags: 3d, computer-vision, sensors

I am working on a sensor grid, that is based on (at the moment) nothing more complicated than cameras. In the future, I would like to include support for Kinect based devices, as well as other sensor equipment (i.e. Microphones, Radio Receivers, etc), but for the moment, I am trying to get it started.

I have gotten the system to track points, observed by cameras, into a 3D environment, but without the rest of the room, it is quite tricky.

So, are there any existing projects that I can work from that are used to convert the outputted images from multiple cameras (in my testing scenario, 5 cameras) into a semi accurate 3D environment that will:

```
1) create the geometry of the room
2) map the images from the cameras into textures that can be overlaid
```

to produce a single/collection of 3D model(s) of a given environment?

p.s.

The ultimate goal of this system is to create a live 3D environment of my house, along with people and pet movement being tracked... a lofty idea/pipe dream, but it would be a great proof of concept. I just hope it won't require an insane amount of computer hardware

Answer (score 4):

Check out Bundler: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~snavely/bundler/ . This will give you sparse point geometry and work out camera extrinsics.

There's also the PCL project (haven't had a chance to use it yet but it looks awesome): http://www.pointclouds.org/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at some of the 3d reconstruction functions used in [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/calib3d.html). If you're looking to do this with fixed cameras (where you can control the calibration), they have a number of functions which do stereo reconstruction. There is also documented methods of using the Kinect with OpenCV.

Bundler and PMVS (and VisualSfM which is bundler/pmvs GUI-fied using siftGPU) are great standalone applications for this problem as well, but they would not be easy to incorporate into a different project. Furthermore, they were developed on the idea that the input to the algorithms would be large photo collections, or significant coverage of an area from multiple directions. If you have 5 fixed positions, you can control the camera calibration and get a significantly better reconstruction at almost a pixel for pixel level using certain stereo reconstruction algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some information to the comment above:

You can use Visual SFM (based on bundler and cmvs) to create a **dense** 3D reconstruction:

http://ccwu.me/vsfm/

You can also use PMVS in conjunction with Bundler to produce a **dense** point cloud:
http://www.di.ens.fr/pmvs/

And there's also the SFM+CVMS distribution for windows (again, producing a **dense** point cloud):
https://code.google.com/p/osm-bundler/downloads/detail?name=osm-bundler-pmvs2-cmvs-full-32-64.zip